# How to change target url of browser's back button

Tags: javascript, browser, back, browser-history

Thanks for attention.
I searched blow question from a lot of sources but I have not found the correct answer yet.
So I hope you all will help me to resolve it.
If my question is same to some, forgive me please!

My question is "How to change target url of browser's back button"
somethings like that:

```
$(browser_back_btn).click(function () {
      $(this).targetUrl = $(this).targetUrl + "#abcxyz";
})
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Is your app an SPA? You can look into [document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/referrer)

Comment: @DibsyJr On page A, I want to check whether is is accessed by browser back button.

Comment: @nhs3108 is this for ajax?

Comment: I have just found this. It seems to able to help me
https://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/stealing-history-api

Comment: @Baldráni No. I don't use it for ajax.

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty interesting question.

In javascript you have the object

`window.history`

What you could do is replaceTheState of the history when you click on the link to your actual page.

Like : `window.history.replaceState( {}, '', '/google.com');`

If you try as you've said in a comment to check wether or not the user used the back button to access the page. You just have to populate the `{}` and check for it in the load of the page.

For exemple : `window.history.replaceState( {backButtonPresse : true}, 'wtv', location.pathname);`

The best thing to do for you is to have a look at [this from Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).